# Accessing database from adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]Code

```
  holder.mPublic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.mPublic.setSelected(true);
            holder.mPrivate.setSelected(false);
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Reviews").child(mId).child()

        }
    });
    holder.mPrivate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.mPrivate.setSelected(true);
            holder.mPublic.setSelected(false);

        }
    });
```

I want to pass through the UID and change data in it...
the recyclerview item is the UID so each pushId is a new item in the recyclerview and this is the adapter and i want to change the data when an user clicks on a radio button

Comment: Might want to use radio instead of checkbox.

Comment: what is the problem u faced?

Comment: I dont know how to go inside the UID... @Lucefer

Answer (score 0):

First, u need unique ids for each entry(for key). If you not provided, it will be generated automatically like your image.

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Then set value you want to that reference

```
 mDatabase.child("Reviews").child(uniqueId).setValue(valueYouWant);
```

You can incrementally add a child to set value like below

```
mDatabase.child("Reviews").child(uniqueId).child("anyValue").setValue(valueYouWant);
```

Comment: i dont have the value of unique id... its automatically generated push id

Comment: Yeah. If you need to get data from that specific id. U need to create it or u need to know it.